# Como posicionar uma div do lado de outra (React)

Tags: react, div

Não estou conseguindo posicionar uma div do lado de outra quando realizo um map em um Json.
No momento esta ficando um em cima do outro mas preciso que fique ao lado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Arquivo .js aonde chama meu Renderizar familias:

```jsx
return (
        <div>
            <div className="Single-div border-2 border-red-600 text-center leading-10  mx-2">
                <RenderFamilia />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

Arquivo .js que renderiza as familias:

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/Styles.css'

const RenderFamilia = () => {
    const itens = [
        {
            id: "1",
            familia: "Hamburguer",
            descricao: "Hamburguer explosão",
            complemento: "Hamburguer 300 g. bacon, cebloa roxa, queijo, tomate, alface e molho especial.",
            valor: "28,00"
        },
        {
            id: "2",
            familia: "Hamburguer",
            descricao: "Hamburguer top",
            complemento: "Hamburguer 300 g. bacon, cebola roxa, queijo, tomate, alface e molho especial",
            valor: "28,00"
        },
        {
            id: "3",
            familia: "Hamburguer",
            descricao: "Hamburguer familia",
            complemento: "Hamburguer 300 g. bacon, cebloa roxa, queijo, tomate, alface e molho especial.",
            valor: "28,00"
        },
        {
            id: "4",
            familia: "Hamburguer",
            descricao: "Hamburguer costela",
            complemento: "Hamburguer 300 g. bacon, cebloa roxa, queijo, tomate, alface e molho especial.",
            valor: "28,00"
        },
        {
            id: "6",
            familia: "pizza",
            descricao: "pizza calabresa",
            complemento: "Hamburguer 300 g. bacon, cebloa roxa, queijo, tomate, alface e molho especial.",
            valor: "28,00"
        },
        {
            id: "7",
            familia: "pizza",
            descricao: "pizza mmussarela",
            complemento: "Hamburguer 300 g. bacon, cebloa roxa, queijo, tomate, alface e molho especial.",
            valor: "28,00"
        },
        {
            id: "8",
            familia: "pizza",
            descricao: "pizza milho",
            complemento: "Hamburguer 300 g. bacon, cebola roxa, queijo, tomate, alface e molho especial.",
            valor: "28,00"
        }
    ]
    let renderizar = true;
    let familia = '';
    const final = itens.map(item => {
        familia == item.familia ? renderizar = false : renderizar = true;
        familia = item.familia;
        return (
            <div key={item.id} className="">
                {renderizar ?
                    <div className="text-red-600 border-2 h-7 ">
                        <div className="">
                            <font size="2" face="verdana">
                                <b>
                                    {item.familia}
                                </b>
                            </font>
                        </div>
                    </div> : ''}
            </div>
        );
    });
    return (
        <div>
            {final}
        </div>
    );
}
export default RenderFamilia;
```

Arquivo Css:

```css
  .Single-div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EM seu código, em nenhum momento foi usada a classe que você descreveu no Style.css. tente colocar na primeira classname do final()

```
...
          return (
            <div key={item.id} className="Single-div">
                {renderizar ?
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Eu tinha usado a classe neste momento:

```jsx
return (
        <div>
            <div className="Single-div border-2 border-red-600 text-center leading-10  mx-2">
                <RenderFamilia />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

Mas alterei para sua sugestão e deu certo, só tive que mudar a classe Css para ficar mais apresentável:

```jsx
  .Single-div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).